# Image not respecting max-height in Firefox

Tags: javascript, image, firefox, html

Portrait img contained within a div does not get it's height set correctly... in FF(27.0.1) only. Works with Chrome, and IE8.

I have the following:

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  padding:0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.photo-container {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 79%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
img#photo {
  margin-top: 0.5%;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 95%;
}
```

In the html...

```
<div class="photo-container">
  <div id="pic"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function f_pop(theImg) {
      document.getElementById('pic').innerHTML = "<img id='photo' src='" + theImg + "' alt='photo'>";
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/sFZgn

Notes:

- The photograph is portrait orientation.
- This works with Chrome and IE8, but not in FF 27.0.1
- In the img#photo, I changed the height    to 50%. Chrome and IE8
  sized the photo down. In FF it was truncated (and required the div's scroll bar to move down).

I initially had this (without the `photo-container`) as a page in a frameset, that is the hierarchy was `body, div id=pic`. It worked in that design with FF.
I converted the frameset to a single page with two column (divs), the right side being the `photo-container`, and now it does not work in FF.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Start by closing your unclosed `div`.

Comment: My apologies. The missing </div> is an omission while creating this post. It is there in the original code. I have updated the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by removing the div around the img. (This is what I had in my frameset version, and I'm not sure why I added it to this 2 column div version).
Also changed the photo-container from a class to a id.
So the only change in the CSS is `.photo-container` becomes `#photo-container`.

The html

```
<div id="photo-container">
    <img id="photo" src="default.gif" alt="photo">
    <div id="blurb"></div>
    <div id="contributor"></div>
</div>
```

The js

```
document.getElementById('photo').src = pic;
document.getElementById('blurb').innerHTML = blurb;
document.getElementById('contributor').innerHTML = contributor;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a height on `#pic`:

```
#pic {
    height: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/sFZgn/2/

Comment: This works for the code I submitted. But I have subsequently added enhancements to the page. This solution causes them to break in all browsers. Below the photo is now a blurb, and below that the contributor name of the photo. 
`<div id="blurb">This is a blurb</div>
    <div id="contributor">Joe Schmoe</div>`
The blurb and contributor are hidden. Various other combinations or exclusions of the height and max-height on both #pic and img#photo either do not display them, or overlay them on the photo, or leave a big gap between the bottom of the photo and the blurb. See fiddle

Comment: Due to the new blurb and contributor divs, the #pic height cannot be 100%. Probably 95% (of photo-container). But this ends up leaving a gap between the pic and blurb.